WSO2 API Manager - Logging Error Responses Using Log Mediator
I am working with WSO2 API Manager and need to log error responses sent back to clients for further processing.
Specifically, I want to capture and log error responses like the following:
xml
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
    <am:code>700700</am:code>
    <am:message>API blocked</am:message>
    <am:description>This API has been blocked temporarily. Please try again later or contact the system administrators.</am:description>
</am:fault>

I’ve tried adding a log mediator to both the fault sequence and the out sequence, but the logs are not appearing as expected.
Here is the configuration I used:
xml
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="custom-log">
    <log category="INFO" level="full"/>
</sequence>

Despite this, the full payload is not being printed to the console.
